# Shared memory not allocating?

Tags: c, shared-memory

I am attempting to allocate some amount of shared memory based on a variable `shmsz` which is always some multiple of 8. In most cases, it's either 8 or 16.

Using the following code:

```
// allocate shared memory
if ((shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, shmsz, IPC_CREAT | 0666)) < 0) {
  printf("Could not allocate shared memory.\n");
  exit(1);
}
```

This used to work like a charm. But now, I am *always* getting the error message and having my program exit on me.

**EDIT**: `errno()` shows "Bus Error: 10"

Comment: How about looking at the value of `errno` when the call fails, that might give a hint...

Comment: And what does the `errno` say?

Comment: EDIT: My apologies, error shows the following: `Bus error: 10` but I am new to all this, so I am unsure what to make of it.

Comment: Change that third line to: `printf("Could not allocate shared memory: %d.\n", errno);` and tell us what it says.  There's a whole boatload of reasons this system call can fail.  http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/shmget.2.html

Comment: I am getting `errno` undeclared, but when I use `errno()` I get "Bus Error: 10"

Comment: Don't forget `#include <errno.h>`

Comment: Seems you are getting a signal SIGBUS and the program is terminating at that point.Are you sure the signal is due to this line or any subsequent lines? What is the plaform? is there any core files generated? Can you run gdb on that core file to see exactly which line is generating SIGBUS? Here most likely errno may not help. At least, this line with shmz = 8, is not raising any SIGBUS in my Fedora 15. The shm segment is successfully created.Can you pl. paste some more code, before/after this line?

Comment: Use the include that @Nikolai suggests (that I forgot) and printing errno before going down too deep a rabbit hole.

Comment: @clintp, getting a signal here SIGBUS. will errno help? Perhaps the error is there where the attachment is done.

Comment: Make sure you `#include <errno.h>` and `<string.h>`, then run `printf("%s\n", strerror(errno))` immediately after the call fails.

Comment: `errno` is not a function - you cannot call it with `()`, it's an integer value for all purposes.

Comment: @Tanmoy a simple restart fixed it. I'm wondering if I somehow used up all my shared memory? (No idea). Do I need to detach it? Free it? I'm doing neither.

Comment: @JordanScales, Pl. check many be another terminal using the ipcs commnand. It will be detached when your code exits. But you need to delete it from the system when you are done. They are not automatically deleted.For this you need to use the shmctl with command value IPC_RMID.Seems due to use of the IPC_PRIVATE key you are ending up creating one shared memory   for every run of the program.You could have used ftok to generate a key and pass it to shmget.  Anyhow, I hope if you add that shmctl, before your code exits, the current shared memory will be deleted and this problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, when there is a violation of access in that shared memory (such as trying to write in a shared memory where you have read-only), the process receives a SIGSEGV or [SIGBUS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGBUS).

In your case, as you are creating it with 0666, there is only one possible situation for this scenario: so are you trying to execute code from that shared memory?